# WP Pagination not working inside of a section

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my website (using WordPress as a 'CMS') and it's working perfectly. I've done and 'migrated' all bootstrap to WP and it's very pretty. Already done some custom post types and custom fields for my projects portfolio.

I'm having only one problem here and that is with the pagination inside of specific div where is the portfolio and custom post type 'projects'. Take a look at printscreen not of my project but I have something similar.

http://imageshack.com/a/img538/2665/OxEfZu.png

I really need a pagination after 6 elements (projects) appears. Tried some codes I've found at internet (wordpress forum, stackoverflow). None of these worked. Also tried a pagination which I have of another WordPress work and isn't working too.

**CODE:**

```
<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Projeto', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#portfolioModal<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-projetos', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get that screenshot to open but it sounds like you want to reload the contents of the div using ajax pagination so that the rest of the page doesn't reload right?

There are loads of tutorials on how to achieve ajax pagination.  here for example: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination--wp-23099

Comment: Hmm.. I need to try to figure out if is this problem. Strange, the printscreen opens here. Basically what I want is to do a pagination but in a specific section of page, only where all my projects, portfolio is. And there is no other pages in my theme, it's a theme with only one page.

Comment: Ajax is quite complicated so you could cheat by loading all the posts in by adding 'posts_per_page' => -1 to your query arguments and then in the loop using a counter to split the posts up into different divs and then using some simple jQuery to hide/show the different divs when the pagination is clicked.  If you can post your code up here then I can try and help.

Comment: Of course I can! Tonight I'll edit the main post and post my code there. Thanks until now!

Comment: code updated ! Sorry for the delay. Hope you could help. Thanks until now.